# Where can I legally read HxH manga in English?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter, resources

I'm going on a trip and want to read some manga on the airplane.

So I was wondering if there is a way to legally download manga to a PC?

Comment: What do you mean by legal? To buy them is the only legal option you have. Online or from a shop.  Otherwise there are tons of sites which offer free "legal" almost any type of manga, as such as HxH.

Comment: @pap  the statement "tons of sites which offer free "legal" almost any" may as well say leave out the "legal" bit, as we all know what air quotes around a term implies.   A&M has a page about legal places to read manga online.  Also, several airlines have wi-fi now.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by one of the commenters, you're going to just have to go and buy digital versions if you want to read it offline on your PC legally.

I took a look at Viz Media's [Hunter x Hunter web page](https://www.viz.com/read/manga/hunter-x-hunter-vol-32/10773) and found the places where they sell the manga digitally. Of the four sources listed, I found that Amazon and Nook sell Hunter x Hunter at the cheapest price of $4.49 per tankobon volume. Amazon has an actual desktop application for both Windows and Macs, while Nook only has a Windows store application, so I think Amazon might be the better way to go if you do not have Windows 8, 8.1, or 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy it on [iBooks Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/id843409292).

Comment: which is less expensive. ibooks or amazon?

Comment: It seems iBooks is limited only to Apple devices.